# Problems with installing things about PIP Python

Tags: python, roblox

I saw something as Roblox Developer which is ro-py: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/use-python-to-interact-with-the-roblox-api-with-ro-py/1006465/4. I wanted to try it out but I never installed like things about PIP. I throught it's like: Pressing Windows and enter

```
pip install ro-py
```

I did it but in my PyCharm project it hasn't appeared. I already restarted PyCharm and restarted my PC. So like when I enter

```
from ro_py import Client
client = Client()
```

it doesn't find ro_py.

Example:
[image]

Example2:
[image]

Example3:
[image]

Can someone help me to install and set ro-py up?

Answer (score 1):

This happens with windows machines. Try this one, it should work.

PyCharm > select "File" menu > select "Invalidate Caches / Restart" menu option

Comment: Hey. So basiclly I wrote n ow everything like import ro_py... Then I clicked on File and Invalidate Caches. What do I have to tick here?

Clear file system cache and Local History |

Cleardownloaded shared indexes |

Ask before downloading newshared indexes |